# How to detect if video playback was blocked by DRM?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, playback, drm, widevine

Is there a way to detect in JS if the browser didn't display the video because of DRM? Is there a JS event I can listen to or another way to detect if the video is not playing?

If I try to screen record the video on this page for example, I can get audio but not video.

**DRM protected video**
https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/latest/samples/drm/widevine.html